# Speed up a really long for loop

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, iteration

I have a for loop which loops through a dictionary containing lists of indexes. For example; {0: [1,5,...], 1: [2,4,...], ...}. I need to iterate through this and use the index values to produce new dictionaries based on an enormous dataframe (around 80 million rows).

As you can see by the code below I have a method which does work to do this, however, it takes an incredible amount of time to do it. I am hoping there is a way to speed this up by performing the operation in sections multithreaded or otherwise. I have seen other similar questions which suggest writing this in cpython, however, because I am working with a dataframe I dont see how this could be possible.

```
total_list = []
for ind in indexes_per_group:
    ship_list = []

    dataframe_indexes = indexes_per_group[ind]
    for index in dataframe_indexes:
        singleLocation_dict = {}

        singleLocation_dict['lat'] = df.loc[index]['LATITUDE']
        singleLocation_dict['lng'] = df.loc[index]['LONGITUDE']
        
        ship_list.append(singleLocation_dict)
    total_list.append(ship_list)
```

Many thanks for any help on this it will be greatly appreciated

Edit: The dictionary I am looping through comes from pandas groupby function

Comment: Is the DataFrame this grouping is based on still available? I think it is already incredibly inefficient to group to get indices, then convert to dict and then use that values in that dict to address values in the DataFrame again. Using pandas builtin ways for aggregation and indexing is much faster than doing most of it yourself as you did.

Comment: The dataframe is still available, to do what you seem to be suggesting I would need to group the dataframe based on multiple columns having identical values (what groupby does) and then for each group create a list containing dictionaries of data from each row. Essentially, the format; [{}, {}] where each dictionary contains specific data from a row. If there is a way of doing this without iterating then that would be great